# why can't I use as. it offers me to use as! but still the app doesn't run

Tags: swift

I am using swift 1.2 in XCode 6.4
I am casting the types using "as" in the code below:

```
let playSoundVC:PlaysoundViewController = segue.destenationViewController as PlaySoundViewController  
let data = sender = as RecordAudio
```

But it is giving me an error. It says I have to use "as!" instead of "as" in both lines to "force downcast" it. However, when I fix it and using "as!" my app doesn't run. I have read that they made an update that "as" is "as!" now. But why my app still doesn't run ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to downcast (sender has to be **superclass** of RecordAudio):

```
let data = sender as! RecordAudio // make it explicit
```

If you want to upcast (sender has to be **subclass** of RecordAudio):

```
let data = sender as RecordAudio
```

If you want to *cast* the type:

```
let data = RecordAudio(sender)
```

*but then you have to have a correct initializer for the RecordAudio class.*

---

In Swift the syntax has changed with `as` with Swift 1.2

> as! for failable casts — Casts that can fail at runtime are now expressed with the new as! operator to make their potential for runtime failure clear to readers and maintainers of your code. ([link](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22))

Since `as` is a downcast and `destinationViewController` is **not the only** *superclass* of `PlaysoundViewController`. There can be more than one *subclass* of `destinationViewController`.

So it can crash. Therefore you have to add an `!` to make it explicit that you know what you are doing.

---

If it does not run, than maybe `destinationViewController` is not a superclass of `PlaysoundViewController`.

Does `PlaysoundViewController` inherit from the type `destinationViewController` has?

Comment: well, I have two screens (view controllers) which two classes assinged to them. What I am doing is trying to pass data from one to another. Doing a "segue"

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/